# Как убрать автоматический вход в систему Linux XFCE4?

Tags: linux, xfce, xfce4

Linux XFCE4 Как убрать автоматический вход в систему, нужно сделать по паролю, а желательно еще и логин вводить. Пробовать менять параметры /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf но или я не нашел нужной строки или делал что то не так. Поиск в гугле ни к чему не привел.

Comment: `grep -r autologin-user /etc/*` чё выводит?

Comment: для начала выясни, какой у тебя в точности DM — там уже будет понятно, что править...  если не справишься сам с правкой конфига, то лучше приложи его к вопросу...

Comment: @donRumata https://pastebin.com/kAyRyYpN это вывод grep -r autologin-user /etc/*

Comment: @Fat-Zer https://pastebin.com/HcLY6eQF вот файл конфига

Comment: @user1, файлы `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/*.conf` равносильны конфигу...  скорей всего можно просто удалить `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/whonix.conf` (посмотри, нет ли там чего-нить ценного окромя автологина)

Comment: Ну тогда `sudo sed -i '/autologin-user/d' /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/whonix.conf`

Comment: @Fat-Zer в пути `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d` не было файла `whonix.conf`. Помогло просто удаление `lightdm.conf.d`. Спасибо

Comment: @user1, ты снёс всю папку с конфигами? О_о

Comment: @donRumata не всю папку просто файл с конфигом `lightdm.conf.d` и вроде `.d` на конце означает что это бекап так что думаю ничего страшного без этого файла не случится, одно только раскладка пропала на русский, но все лекго поправляется в настройках

Comment: `d` - directory. Если бы ты удалял через шел - обычный `rm` не проканал бы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Настройки > Пользователи и группы > Спрашивать пароль

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Открыть файл `lightdm.conf`:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Закоментировать следующие строки:

```
#autologin-user=uzer
#autologin-user-timeout=0
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).